# Build error when installing qtopcua in qt

Tags: qt, makefile, opc-ua

I followed this tutorial https://blog.basyskom.com/building-qt-opc-ua-with-open62541/ and at this step "mingw32-make install" I get the follwing errors:

```
sed  -e s,D:/Qt/5.14.2/mingw73_64/qtopcua/build/lib,D:/Qt/5.14.2/mingw73_64/lib,g ../../build/lib/pkgconfig/Qt5OpcUa.pc >
D:/Qt/5.14.2/mingw73_64/lib/pkgconfig/Qt5OpcUa.pc sed: can't read ../../build/lib/pkgconfig/Qt5OpcUa.pc: No such file or directory mingw32- 
make[3]: *** [Makefile.Release:5815: install_target] Error 2 mingw32- 
make[3]: Leaving directory 'D:/Qt/5.14.2/mingw73_64/qtopcua/build/src/opcua' mingw32-make[2]: *** 
[Makefile:55: release-install] Error 2 mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/Qt/5.14.2/mingw73_64/qtopcua/build/src/opcua' mingw32-make[1]: *** 
[Makefile:64: sub-opcua-install_subtargets] Error 2 mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Qt/5.14.2/mingw73_64/qtopcua/build/src' mingw32-make: *** 
[Makefile:65: sub-src-install_subtargets] Error 2
```

I'm using qt 5.14.2 and the branch 5.13 (I tried 5.12, 5.14 and got also errors), windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy all missing files manualy to you QDIR.